# Iterating over storage bucket contents in GCP whilst data is streaming into it

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I want to iterate over the contents of a storage bucket at a specific point in time. I have the following code to do this:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")
blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs:
    if "old_name" in blob.name:
        # process file
```

However, items are streaming into my bucket when I do this. The if statement will in theory mean that I will not process anything new that is streaming in, however I am nervous that the iterator will not contain all the blobs as the new files streaming in will mess it up somehow. Do you know if the above code will work or could there be problems and I miss out some of the files.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to do that? Since if you need to check updates in the bucket you can use another approach to do that.

Comment: I want to migrate data that is in a bucket. I want to ensure I migrate all items that are in the bucket when the code starts. If I migrate items that arrive after it starts that is ok but I can't miss anything that is there prior to it starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to migrate data that is in a bucket. I want to ensure I migrate
> all items that are in the bucket when the code starts. If I migrate
> items that arrive after it starts that is ok but I can't miss anything
> that is there prior to it starting

That being the case, you are good. This will work.
The exception wold be if new data overwrites data that you'd like to copy before you get to it, but if there is no overwriting take place, this is just fine.

> But how does the iterator work such that we know it will be ok.
> Doesn't adding items to a list with an iterator change its behaviour?

As seem in the documentation,`.list_blobs` returns a result that is partly "offline": it will fetch one page of results using the API and transparently fetch more pages as the itens in each request are iterated. That is: a new blocking HTTP request is made at each N items, N being the default page size - *but not* on each item consumed on the iterator. If you are not explicitly setting `max_results` it looks like it uses an API default. This means it will make a few requests throughout iteration and new files added between these requests will either show up at the end, or do not show up at all - it would be a very buggy behavior if these new files would spoil the result fetching.

Actually, if the the operator would work as a "live view" of the bucket, fetching an item each time it is iterated, it would have to be fairly complicated - the app using the API would have to work with some sort of parallelism be it multi-threading or async, in which the API code would be able to run and retrieve network data *while* your code is also running. That requires code an order of magnitude more complicated to work - and, would of course, only make sense if it would *benefit* the API user. If a "live content update" call was available, copying with changes in the source bucket would  not only be its duty, but also, the *only* reason for such an implementation.

TL;DR: just go for it -  when `.list_blobs()` return you have an object that can be iterated and contain a local (in opposed to "remote") static set of the objects present in the bucket at the moment the call was processed.

https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html

Comment: But how does the iterator work such that we know it will be ok. Doesn't adding items to a list with an iterator change its behaviour?

Comment: I don't believe that is the case. If you check in the source code it gives you an HTTP iterator. https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/client.html#Client.list_blobs

Comment: You can rest assured it will not break, for the reasons I stated in the second-to-last paragraph. At most will automate the paging behind the scenes, but it would at most include the new itens that arrive between 2 remote pollings - as I stated: there is no sense in provide a live update if the only purpose would be to _break_ if any update actually occurred. If your use case would be to about strictly not fetching any new file _after_ the first request, then, yes, some additional controls would be in order.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I think you're right overall, however I believe your second paragraph is wrong. list_blobs does not return an offline result as it returns an HTTP iterator. i.e. you still have to be connected to the internet when you want to access one of the items from the list.

Comment: After checking the code there, and the docs this is what goes: it returns an iterator that will transparently fetch more result pages when needed, when iterating. This will happen once each Nth call, N being the default result page size. It would be as complicated as I wrote above otherwise, but this is simpler as it makes a whole new blocking HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be simpler. `list_blobs` returns a [lazy iterator](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html). Why not just materialize the list of blobs at the start and then iterate over them? That way you will not see any of the new blobs added to the bucket.

```py
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")
blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs())
print(type(blobs))

>>> <class 'list'>
```

Comment: What happens if a new item is added while blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs()) is being executed